# reuse a template twice within the same controller but show different data

Tags: angularjs

I have a html file which I want to include in two places like:

```
<div ng-if="flag1" ng-include = templatepath></div>
<div ng-if="flag2" ng-include = templatepath></div>
```

```js
$scope.templatepath = 'template.html'
```

### template.html

```
<h2> Name is {{name}} </h2>
```

flag1 and flag2 change when a function is run on-click.
I want name to contain different values. However, when I change name in the controller, both the lines change. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use components:

```
<my-component name="name1"></my-component>
<my-component name="name2"></my-component>
```

```
app.component("myComponent", {
    bindings: { name: '<' },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
```

### template.html

```
<h2> Name is {{$ctrl.name}} </h2>
```

Components use isolate scope and bindings.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)